# How to get access to cookies in react js

Tags: reactjs, axios, woocommerce-rest-api

How to get access to cookies that I get in the response of axios post and get request, Am using WooCommerce Rest API and I need the access to PHPSESSID that I get on response, I tried on postman as it automatically set the cookie to header, Is there anyway to do in React JS?

Comment: Is the Rest API running on the same origin like your app?

Comment: No, Its on different domain, and reactjs app is on local

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: @assembler that doesnt worked, tried that

Answer (score 0):

The fetch API allows you to read the response headers of a request:

```
const getResponse = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("https://stackoverflow.com/");

  // log all response headers
  console.log([...response.headers.entries()])

  // look for set-cookie
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie
  console.log(response.headers.get("set-cookie"));
}
```

However this will only work if the WooCommerce Rest API will set or modify the cookie exactly in that response.

Comment: When i check on network tab, The set-cookie is showing, But when i try to print it, showing undefined

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the cookie isn't included in the response when you make an API call from the client side. To access the cookie on the client side, please use `document.cookie` after making the API request.